# A member of the type, 'CustomerID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name

Tags: entity-framework

I am tring to call the mysql stored procedure using entityframework using below code
  error:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'MangerModuleModel.collection'. A member of the type, 'CustomerID', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

```
public virtual List<collection> Getcollection()
{
    string SQLQuery = "call MangerModule();";
    var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext;
    List<object> listobj = new List<object>();
    List<collection> data = objectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<collection>(SQLQuery).AsQueryable().ToList();
    return data;
}
```

It's showing below error [image]
and my stored procedure output as below

[image]

Where i am doing mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public class columns
{

        public double TotalAmount { get; set; }
        public double Dayamount { get; set; }
        public double monthamount { get; set; }
        public double yearamount { get; set; }

}
```